# Firestore is unusably slow with a simple hello world scenario

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have one collection with a document that has a subcollection of three documents something like this.

```
task-sets: {
   "<owners-uid>": {
       owner: <owners-uid>,
       tasks: {
           "<task 1 id>": {
               name: 'Bake a Cake',
               description: 'Bake a delicious cake with a colorful frosting.'
           },
           "<task 2 id>": {
               name: 'Invite Friends',
               description: 'Invite any friends that might enjoy delicious cake.'
           },
           "<task 3 id>": {
               name: 'Pin Tail on Donkey',
               description: 'Blindfold a guest and have them attempt to pin a paper tail to a poster of a tailless donkey.'
           },
      }
 }
```

I then run this code to get this *one* document.

```
export async function getRemoteTasks() {
    const user = authState.get().user;
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    console.time('getRemoteTasks');

    const taskSetDocument = await db.collection('task-sets').doc(user.uid).get();

    const querySnapshot = await taskSetDocument.ref.collection('tasks').get();

    console.timeEnd('getRemoteTasks');

    let tasks = [];

    querySnapshot.forEach(fillArray(tasks));

    return tasks;
}
```

The two query lines in this function between `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` take 115 seconds to run.

**Please do not duplicate this. Believe me, I've gone through every single one of the slow firestore query questions on SO. All of them are performance problems. My problem is that firestore is broken for me. This is a simple hello world test case with a relatively simple query. It is taking forever. Something is broken here. I need to know what that is. None of the other questions answered my problem at all.**

Maybe its because this is a development run and if I deployed it, it would get faster. Please, I've put so much work into this project as a firebase project, and this one problem is a deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Eureka!** I found my problem and the solution. It was very esoteric. I have a react app. I am using a package called react-ridge-state to hold globally the authentication status of my user. I have an Authentication provider that sets that global state. What I didn't realize is that react-ridge-state causes a component rerender when the state is changed. I suppose that is the point of it. This created an infinite loop rerender. That was causing the slow down, probably because it wasn't letting the promise resolve.

I wish there was a way to increase the visibility of rerender loops like this. This solution came to me in a dream last night, and I put a breakpoint in my code and found the loop. Way to go intuition!

**Solution**: Continuous rendering of components was preventing resolution of the promise returned by firestore.